# What are (if any) possible scenario whereby hacker can find multiple sites hosted in one VPS?

Tags: linux, nginx, security, centos6, php-fpm

Let me clarify: Say that I have 10 sites hosted in one VPS host. And for some reason, one of these sites gets famous and a hacker wants to know where it is hosted, and how many other sites are hosted along this site.

I reckon the first one be as easy as finding out the IP, but without actually  hacking the site, can someone know how many domains are hosted in that IP?

In case you were wondering why I asked, I am hosting around 7 commercial sites and 1 personal site for some programming tips, which I mostly collect/find on the internet. Although *this* site is the most secure it can be (No user inputs, uptodate softwares...), I can't help but imagine if any of these script-kiddies would attempt and find ways to get names of my other domains and that may may put my clients' sites at risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can.

Basically this is a "reverse DNS query" (see the comments for another link).

There are search engines which output you the amount of domains on your IP

See for example

[sameid.net](http://sameid.net/)

as there is most of the time a reason to use SSL for viewing a site or entering data and, unless you do use [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), you would need at least one IP for every domain anyway.

Comment: To make it easier, there is reverse DNS lookup available to anyone (http://remote.12dt.com/)